# Failed to join peer to the channel with error :: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [] creator org

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I was trying to create a new org in balance transfer application 1.4.3 version.

Started the network, I tried to run all the REST API's as per the documentation.

After registering users on all 3 orgs, created a new channel with mychannel.
Then I tried to join all the peers to all 3 orgs to mychannel.

I was able to join peers to org1 and org2 to mychannel through REST API, but when send to join peers to org3 to join mychannel it was giving below error.

```
curl -s -X POST http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/peers -H "authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1Njk0MzgzNTIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiUmFtZXNoIiwib3JnTmFtZSI6Ik9yZzMiLCJpYXQiOjE1Njk0MDIzNTJ9.iyMdcz7zYgR6bQHuWBQXrgYJ8U_wXsdDEZ8rOTR4Fvs" -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"peers": ["peer0.org3.example.com","peer1.org3.example.com"]}'
```

> [ERROR] Join-Channel - Failed to join all peers to channel. cause:Failed to join peer to the channel with error :: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [] creator org [Org3MSP]

Comment: is it possible you left out org3 from the channel configuration in configtx.yml?

Comment: Did required changes in below files, just added one more organization org3. 
*
artifacts/channel/crytogen.yaml,
artifacts/channel/configtx.yaml,
artifacts/channel/docker-compose.yaml,
artifacts/network-config.yaml,
artifacts/org3.yaml,
config.js,
app/instantiate-chaincode.js*